# Prevent "click through" on multi-toggle menu

Tags: menu, toggle, responsive

I'm currently working on the Responsive side of a website and I'm facing some problems that I don't really know how to fix. I've been looking for some clues for a couple of hours now : nothing so far.

Here's my problem, I have a basic nav composed of multiple Links and Unordered Lists (which also contain links) that can be opened / closed by touching a "Hamburger" menu :

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BovMl.png

Item 1, 2 and 3 open when touched :

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fsSt.png

My first problem is here, the menu does not fully show on the screen and is not scrollable, the background content scroll instead. I tried to activate the scrolling by setting overflow-y to scroll on the whole menu but the result is not that smooth.

The second problem is a more serious one, when I first toggle 'Item 1', toggling 'Item 2' will result in opening right away 'Item 2-2'. I've noticed that 'Item 2-2' is at the same place than 'Item 2' on the first picture I've posted because 'Item 1' closes so 'Item 2' get up and opens but I don't know how to prevent this "ghost" click to happen.

I don't know if I was clear enough, sorry for the low explanations, english isn't my native language so I'm trying the best I can :/

Thanks in advance !